# Overflow Scroll not working on MacOS Safari 13 and below

Tags: css, safari, overflow

I have a category menu and list of projects whereby on the `main` tag we have

```css
margin-top: 250px;
height: calc(100vh - 250px);
```

From the above, if the projects' container has a height bigger than `calc(100vh - 250px)`, then by default it's scrollable.

If the projects' container has a height smaller than `calc(100vh - 250px)`, then we `flex-end` everything (menu, container) to the bottom of the page. The projects container has `overflow-y: scroll;`

This is working perfectly in all browsers except MacOS (Catalina) Safari 13 and below.

In Safari 13, all the projects that are supposed to be scrollable are reduced in height to fit the available height calc(100vh - 250px).

Normal and expected view

[image]

Faulty view Safari 13, using https://testingbot.com/ to test
[image]

You can view the page here https://category-scrollings.tiiny.site/ (Free trial expiring in 7 days).

```js
const panels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".projects-container"));
  const menus = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item"));

  menus.forEach(function (menu) {
    menu.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      console.log("event:", event.target);
      menus.forEach(function (_menu, index) {
        const _panel = panels[index];
        _menu.classList.remove("clicked");
        _panel.classList.remove("active");
      });
      const panelId = `${event.target.id.split("-")[0]}-panel`;
      const panel = document.getElementById(panelId);
      event.target.classList.add("clicked");
      panel.classList.add("active");
    });
  });
```

```css
 body {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  main {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .container {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 250px;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: calc(50vw - 25px);
    height: calc(100vh - 250px);
  }

  .nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    top: 200px;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .nav-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 0.688rem;
    line-height: 1.334rem;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: "ABC Favorit", sans-serif;
    color: #ccc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.6px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-right: 16px;
  }

  .nav-item.clicked {
    color: #000;
  }

  .projects-container.active {
    display: flex;
  }

  .projects-container {
    display: none;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-center;
    -webkit-box-align: flex-center;
    -ms-flex-align: flex-center;
    align-items: center;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .projects {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-align: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  .project {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 0.9px solid #d9d9d9;
  }

  .boxes {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 140px;
  }

  .box {
    display: block;
    height: 27px;
    width: 7px;
  }

  .box.blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .box.white {
    background-color: white;
  }

  .box.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  .box.red {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .box.black {
    background-color: black;
  }

  .title-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 355px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 9px 0;
  }

  .title {
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-family: "ABC Favorit", sans-serif;
    max-width: 255px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 0.875rem;
    margin-top: 1.7px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
      <div id="all-menu" class="nav-item clicked">All</div>
      <div id="cars-menu" class="nav-item">Cars</div>
      <div id="fashion-menu" class="nav-item">Fashion</div>
    </div>
    <div id="all-panel" class="projects-container all active">
      <div class="projects">
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">AMDILK VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">AMDILK VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">AMDILK VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">AMDILK VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">AMDILK VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">AMDILK VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">AMDILK VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">AMDILK VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">AMDILK VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">AMDILK VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">IULH VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ULHF VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">UYJHF VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">UYJHF VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">UYJHF VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">UYJHF VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">UYJHF VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ALIUIYF VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">HEYsh VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">YTKGUIY VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">rjke VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="cars-panel" class="projects-container cars">
      <div class="projects">
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ZUKUNFT VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">AMDILK VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">IULH VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="fashion-panel" class="projects-container fashion">
      <div class="projects">
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">UYJHF VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">ALIUIYF VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">HEYsh VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">YTKGUIY VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div class="box yellow"></div>
            <div class="box white"></div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div class="box black"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-container">
            <p class="title">rjke VERBINDEN</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Click `Expand Snippet` to see all

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer myself. It appears I needed to assign a height to the `project` class

```css
// either
.project {
   ...
   height: 35px;
}

// Or 
.project {
   ...
   min-height: fit-content;
   height: 100%;
}
```